# UBUNTU's Network Connection Manger can't detect Huawei ETS2051 Modem device!

Tags: software-center, usb-modem, wvdial

I have a modem device called **[Huawei ETS2051](http://www.globalyt.com/imageRepository/65b40d65-ec07-41ed-8288-e4862424fbe4.jpg)** and the **Network Connection Manger** can't detect it, but when I use Gnome-PPP it work fine but the problem is when I use **Gnome-PPP**; apps like **Ubuntu software Center** Can't reconice that's Iam connecting to the Internet so the app is just act like it's offline while other apps like web browsers and IM's work good under **Gnome-PPP**. any way what I want is to have a Full Ubuntu experince by making The Network Connection Manger detect my **ETS2051**.

More information:
**Gnome-PPP** is a GUI for wvdial.
the **ETS2051** modem use a serial USB port.
I have a Windows driver CD for the device.
I have also find [This qustion](https://askubuntu.com/questions/103485/wvdial-connection-wont-support-ubuntu-software-centre) about the software Center acting like it's offline around wvdial and there's [this launchpad bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/software-center/+bug/880830).
 and am really insest to use Ubuntu Software Center so please no other software manger apps recomendation...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this, you can simply stop the Network Manger and everything will run great including Ubuntu Software Center!
stop it by run this commend in the terminal:

```
sudo stop network-manager
```

you can bring it back by restart your computer or simply run this:

```
sudo start network-manager
```

that's it how easy fix, but hard to get the right answer nowadays!

Answer (score -1):

**open Synaptic Package Manager Type "Smartlink" into the search field in the Synaptic Package Manager and install all of smarlink package. http://www.ehow.com/how_5435902_install-modem-drivers-ubuntu.html#ixzz2BcaT8Ean it works with me very well**

Comment: What is Smartlink? Please include the essential parts of the answer in your post, [that's better than just posting a link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers/8259#8259)